# "Sequence contains no elements" error in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework-5

When I try to retrieve an object from a local database, it throws an exception

> Sequence contains no elements

However I have added sample data into database. What can cause this error?

```
private void BindObjectToControls()
{
    Item = new Item();

    //set values entered by user into UI to corresponding properties of the object
    try
    {
        Item.Description = cbxType.Text.ToString() + ", " + tbxDesc.Text;
        Item.Category = (string)cbxCategory.SelectedItem;
        Item.Brand = (string)cbxBrand.SelectedItem;
        Item.Price = (int)nudPrice.Value;
    }
    catch(NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
    }
}

private void Save()
{
    BindObjectToControls();

    ComputerUZEntities db = new ComputerUZEntities();

    if (isNew)
    {
        db.Items.Add(Item);
    }
    else
    {
        Item myItem = (from ctx in db.Items where ctx.ItemID == Item.ItemID select ctx).Single();
        //Item is global variable.
        myItem.Description = Item.Description;
        myItem.Category = Item.Category;
        myItem.Brand = Item.Brand;
        myItem.Price = Item.Price;
    }

    db.Items.SqlQuery(sql);
    db.SaveChanges();

    MessageBox.Show("Saved!");

    this.Close();
}
```

P.S I have tried all 4 calls `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault`. None of them has worked.

Comment: You say that ID is already in the database, I find that to be very unlikely. Put a breakpoint on your query, find the ID, and then manually check the database for it. Also, having a global variable which represents an item you're attaching to a EF context is a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry previous version wasn't understandable, I've added more lines of code. So Item is global variable and instantiated in BindObjectToControls method, then Save method is calling that method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is not with those 4 calls. The problem is that you are creating new object everytime when `BindObjectToControls()` method is called. Instead of creating a `new Item()` inside of `BindObjectToControls()`, Try to make inside constructor or somewhere else.